# sql - order by based on 2 column( first sort column 1 ) and then column 2

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table named `EMPLOYEE` containing the following attributes

```
(EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, JOB_ID, MANAGER_ID, Salary)
```

Can I list out the employee details according to their last_name in ascending order and salaries in descending order?

Comment: So Smith makes $40K, Manson makes $50K, and Zulu makes $35K. What order do you want?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, this isn't clear from the question body, but the title clarifies the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can sort by multiple column. Just seperate by comma

```
select * from employee
order by last_name asc, salary desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE 
ORDER BY LAST_NAME ASC, Salary DESC
```

Comment: opss this what happens when you are watching Breaking Bad and trying to answer a question on SO lol

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from employee order by salary desc,last_name asc
```